# ddclient on alpine-linux

Tags: alpine-linux

I have a problem with the ddclient service on alpine-linux.
I followed the directions as from https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Ddclient, but as soon as I try to start the service I get a warning that it is crasched.
The log files are sparse and don't help me figure out where the problem lies.

Jan 18 10:36:57 routern3 user.debug : Will stop /usr/sbin/ddclient

Jan 18 10:36:57 routern3 daemon.err /etc/init.d/ddclient[6995]: start-stop-daemon: no matching processes found

Jan 18 10:42:47 routern3 daemon.err /etc/init.d/ddclient[7060]: status: crashed

I attach the following files:

debug: https://pastebin.com/TKK9aMGw

ddclient service: https://pastebin.com/SjuHwtSS

ddclient.conf: https://pastebin.com/eKYDudGa

routern3:~# rc-service ddclient start

- Starting ddclient ... [ ok ]
  routern3:~# rc-service ddclient status
- status: crashed

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated that wiki page:
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Ddclient

Also, I've packaged ddclient so that is available
in the official edge repository: https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/commit/?h=master

For now, is available in testing.

Feel free to provide a feedback in https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org so that ddclient can be moved to community repository and be added to the next stable version of alpine.

More information about edge/stable repositories:
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_edge_and_stable_releases.3F

Hope it helps.

.: Francesco